# How to fetch data between two dates using axios library

Tags: javascript, axios

How fetch data between two dates with axios ?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
const res = axios.get("/activities", {
  params: {
    date: {
      gte: startDate,
      lte: endDate
    },
    user: id
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems the issue is at backend as the backend should revert you the right data based on the parameters passed.

Comment: I work with Strapi

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:axios] or [tag:reactjs]. It has to do with the endpoint you're querying and what parameters it expects, encoded in what way, etc.

Comment: Please include your server code. Maybe your query because what you've posted does not relate to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I read the documentation of strapi and I have the issue :

```
const res = axios.get("/activities", {
      params: {
        date_lt: startDate,
        user: id
      }
    });
```

It's not precise to add _lt or _gt at the end of the value I want to check